# DrawerListener overwritten in double Drawers Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, slidingdrawer

I have a main Activity with two different drawers:
- A navigation one on the left side
- A notification one on the right side

The layout **main.xml** is the following:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.toto.MainActivity">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.test.toto.NavigationDrawer" />

    <fragment android:id="@+id/notification_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:name="com.test.toto.NotificationDrawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In my main activity **MainActivity.java** I do the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mNavigationDrawer = (NavigationDrawer)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mNotificationDrawer = (NotificationDrawer)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.notification_drawer);

    // Set up the drawers
    mNavigationDrawer.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    mNotificationDrawer.setUp(
            R.id.notification_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}
```

And in both drawer fragments there is the setUp method (ex. **NotificationDrawer.java**) :

```
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.END);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        };

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
```

My problem is that the mDrawerLayout will be the same one in both setup (R.id.drawer_layout) and so the setDrawerListener method is overwritten with the new Listener when I call the setUp the second time (in my case the Navigation one is replaced my the Notification one).

For this reason, the methods to interact between the navigation drawer and the action bar (**onDrawerClosed** and **onDrawerOpened**) are not called for the Navigation Drawer.

**How can I get these methods called for both drawers?**
I need to do something in both cases when one or the other drawer is opened.

Answer (score 0):

Your listener has to handle both drawers. In your OnDrawerOpened and OnDrawerClosed, you'll have to check which drawer you have in argument and use the right code.